# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/Map(<lambda at bigquery.py:2157>)']

Tags: python, google-bigquery, apache-beam

In Python, I'm trying to write local JSON to my bigquery table with Apache Beam. But I keep getting this error:

```
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py:2028: BeamDeprecationWarning: options is deprecated since First stable release. References to <pipeline>.options will not be supported
  is_streaming_pipeline = p.options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming
2.48.0: Pulling from apache/beam_java11_sdk
Digest: sha256:ab9e4fb16e4a3b8090309ceed1f22c0d7de64ee9f27d688e4a35145cabbfa179
Status: Image is up to date for apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.48.0
docker.io/apache/beam_java11_sdk:2.48.0
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
d8aaf6813f9c5df568e0f7c97947e802950a0ce598796bcb59660109baa51e9f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1418, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 624, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1582, in handle_process_outputs
    self._write_value_to_tag(tag, windowed_value, watermark_estimator)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1695, in _write_value_to_tag
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 239, in receive
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 198, in update_counters_start
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 213, in update_from
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 265, in do_sample
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1506, in get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 209, in get_estimated_size_and_observables
    return self.estimate_size(value, nested), []
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1584, in estimate_size
    value_size = self._value_coder.estimate_size(value)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 248, in estimate_size
    self.encode_to_stream(value, out, nested)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1769, in encode_to_stream
    component_coder.encode_to_stream(attr, out, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1170, in encode_to_stream
    self._elem_coder.encode_to_stream(elem, out, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1769, in encode_to_stream
    component_coder.encode_to_stream(attr, out, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 270, in encode_to_stream
    return stream.write(self._encoder(value), nested)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 429, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myaccount/projects/myproj/Outdoor Elements/filter.py", line 275, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/myaccount/projects/myproj/Outdoor Elements/filter.py", line 266, in main
    beam_to_DB(output_json, "myproj-324103:viewable_datasets." + item, "/Users/myaccount/projects/myproj/Outdoor Elements/schema.json")
  File "/Users/myaccount/projects/myproj/Outdoor Elements/filter.py", line 58, in beam_to_DB
    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 577, in run
    return self.runner.run_pipeline(self, self._options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/direct/direct_runner.py", line 129, in run_pipeline
    return runner.run_pipeline(pipeline, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 202, in run_pipeline
    self._latest_run_result = self.run_via_runner_api(
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 224, in run_via_runner_api
    return self.run_stages(stage_context, stages)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 455, in run_stages
    bundle_results = self._execute_bundle(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 783, in _execute_bundle
    self._run_bundle(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 1012, in _run_bundle
    result, splits = bundle_manager.process_bundle(
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/fn_runner.py", line 1348, in process_bundle
    result_future = self._worker_handler.control_conn.push(process_bundle_req)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/fn_api_runner/worker_handlers.py", line 379, in push
    response = self.worker.do_instruction(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 629, in do_instruction
    return getattr(self, request_type)(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py", line 667, in process_bundle
    bundle_processor.process_bundle(instruction_id))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 1061, in process_bundle
    input_op_by_transform_id[element.transform_id].process_encoded(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py", line 231, in process_encoded
    self.output(decoded_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 528, in output
    _cast_to_receiver(self.receivers[output_index]).receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1420, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1492, in _reraise_augmented
    raise exn
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1418, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 624, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1582, in handle_process_outputs
    self._write_value_to_tag(tag, windowed_value, watermark_estimator)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1695, in _write_value_to_tag
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1420, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1492, in _reraise_augmented
    raise exn
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1418, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 624, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1582, in handle_process_outputs
    self._write_value_to_tag(tag, windowed_value, watermark_estimator)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1695, in _write_value_to_tag
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 240, in receive
    self.consumer.process(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 908, in process
    delayed_applications = self.dofn_runner.process(o)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1420, in process
    self._reraise_augmented(exn)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1508, in _reraise_augmented
    raise new_exn.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1418, in process
    return self.do_fn_invoker.invoke_process(windowed_value)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 624, in invoke_process
    self.output_handler.handle_process_outputs(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1582, in handle_process_outputs
    self._write_value_to_tag(tag, windowed_value, watermark_estimator)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/common.py", line 1695, in _write_value_to_tag
    self.main_receivers.receive(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 239, in receive
    self.update_counters_start(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/operations.py", line 198, in update_counters_start
    self.opcounter.update_from(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 213, in update_from
    self.do_sample(windowed_value)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/opcounters.py", line 265, in do_sample
    self.coder_impl.get_estimated_size_and_observables(windowed_value))
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1506, in get_estimated_size_and_observables
    self._value_coder.get_estimated_size_and_observables(
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 209, in get_estimated_size_and_observables
    return self.estimate_size(value, nested), []
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1584, in estimate_size
    value_size = self._value_coder.estimate_size(value)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 248, in estimate_size
    self.encode_to_stream(value, out, nested)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1769, in encode_to_stream
    component_coder.encode_to_stream(attr, out, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1170, in encode_to_stream
    self._elem_coder.encode_to_stream(elem, out, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 1769, in encode_to_stream
    component_coder.encode_to_stream(attr, out, True)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coder_impl.py", line 270, in encode_to_stream
    return stream.write(self._encoder(value), nested)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 429, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/Map(<lambda at bigquery.py:2157>)']

File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/apache_beam/coders/coders.py", line 429, in encode
    return value.encode('utf-8')

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode' [while running 'WriteToBigQuery/Map(<lambda at bigquery.py:2157>)']
```

My code:

```
import os
import glob
import json
import geopandas as gpd
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io.gcp.internal.clients import bigquery
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery_tools import parse_table_schema_from_json

def beam_to_DB(data, db_table, schema):

    if isinstance(schema, str):
        with open(schema, 'r') as file:
            schema = json.load(file)

    # Create a pipeline.
    pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
    pcollection = pipeline | beam.Create([data])

    # Write data to BigQuery.
    pcollection | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
        db_table,
        schema={"fields": schema},
        method='BATCH_INSERT',
        write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
        create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)

    # Run the pipeline.
    pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
```

How can I determine what in my code is causing this error?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the stack trace, to see where the error began?

Comment: @TheTridentGuy I added the full stack trace

Comment: Hi @zakdances, did the answer below help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew No, I'm still unsure what to do. I don't see what part of my code is causing the problem.

Comment: Hi @zakdances,I have posted an answer. I hope it will help you. Do consider upvoting and accepting if it helps, otherwise let me know so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logs to find errors in your code. Using logs, you can find from which part of your code the error is generated. You can consider the following as an example.

**test.json**

```
{
   "fields": [{
       "name": "name", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }, {
       "name": "age", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"
   }]
}
```

**test.py**

```
db_table='dataset.table'
data=[{ 'name': 'a', 'age':46 }, { 'name': 'c', 'age': 24 },]
table_schema='./test.json'

class logs(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self,element):
      logging.info("Data is   %s ", element)

def beam_to_DB(data, db_table, schemas):

   if isinstance(schemas, str):
       with open(schemas, 'r') as file:
           schemas = json.load(file)


   pipeline = beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options)
   pcollection = pipeline |'Pcollection create' >> beam.Create(data)
   pcollection| 'logging_pcollection' >> beam.ParDo(logs())
   try:
       pcollection|'Write to BigQuery' >> WriteToBigQuery(table=db_table, schema=schemas,method='BATCH_INSERT', create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
   except Exception as e:
       logging.error(f"Exception in Write to BigQuery - {str(e)}")
   pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()


beam_to_DB(data, db_table, table_schema)
```

**Graph view:**

[image]

It sounds like the error you're getting is coming from either json or the data you're passing. In the above example I have provided the json, data I am used to execute the code successfully and I also included the log function. I hope this answer will help you.